# MatLab silent install wait for next action until setup is finished

Tags: matlab

I tried to implement on windows using powershell what was discussed here:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/412882-silent-install-wait-for-next-action-until-setup-is-finished

Which basically says:

> instead of running setup.exe from root folder execute setup.exe from folder \bin\win64\setup.exe

But that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using powershell.  You can do the following to force script to wait until install is completed:

```
&setup.exe -inputfile .\input_file.txt | Out-Null
```

The following site is where I found this information:

http://www.noelpulis.com/fix-powershell-does-not-wait-before-starting-the-next-command/